# masonry grid with vue js 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, masonry

I am looking for advice to display complex masonry grid with a lot of items ( >1k ) with VueJS 2. Restrictions is using only ES5 syntax, because this is project requirement.

Please give a tips how to build it very performant, preferably pure VueJS 2 without using 3rd party libraries like https://isotope.metafizzy.co/ or https://masonry.desandro.com/

Pure CSS solutions also not relevant, because content will load dynamicaly and items order is make sense. All pure CSS technics use columns and order become broken after new elements of the grid arrives.

Thank you!